# Ember Integration Test Component Within Component

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, integration-testing, ember-bootstrap

I have installed `ember-bootstrap` in my application. Then, I created a login-form component.

In the `app/templates/components/login-form.hbs`, there are 2 Bootstrap `input` and 1 `button`, which are the following:

```
{{#bs-form onSubmit=(action "login") as |form| }}
    {{#form.group validation=emailValidation}}
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input id="email" value={{email}} name="email" class="form-control" oninput={{action (mut email) value="target.value"}} type="text" placeholder="Email" required>
    {{/form.group}}
    {{#form.group validation=passwordValidation}}
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input id="password" value={{password}} name="password" class="form-control" oninput={{action (mut password) value="target.value"}} type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    {{/form.group}}
    {{bs-button defaultText="Login" type="primary" buttonType="submit"}}
{{/bs-form}}
```

When I do integration test in Components, it does not seem to identify `this`.

```
test('it renders', function(assert) {
  assert.expect(3);
  assert.equal(this.$('input').attr('name'),'email','has Email');
  assert.equal(this.$('input').attr('name'),'password','has Password');
  assert.equal(this.$('button').text(),'Login','has Login');
});
```

In the `input`, I get `undefined` results. What is the proper way to call input for a `form.group` component in Bootstrap, to be used in the component testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have forgotten to render the component within your test; that is you need to add the following:

```
this.render(hbs`{{login-form}}`);
```

before asserting anything. You also need to change your second assertion to assert the second input within your component. Anyway; I have copied your component and corrected your test in the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/b07f1fbc8a6722f735573abbaf7bf660?openFiles=tests.integration.components.login-form-test.js%2Ctemplates.components.login-form.hbs). I hope it helps.

Comment: I've edited my question, but it still is the same topic. Also, I added a screenshot. Do you happen to know how to render in `{{form.group}}`, `{{bs-button}}` and `{{bs-form}}` in test? Maybe that's the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: did you check the twiddle i have provided?

Comment: Thanks for making it clear. I'm kinda new to testing, and thanks for showing me Twiddle. It works.